# Adverb before verb in sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, adverbs, word-order

"This area is monitored constantly" vs. "this area is constantly monitored"

Which is grammatically correct?

Comment: Answered at [Position of adverb "implicitly"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62718/position-of-adverb-implicitly) (in the particular case here, either alternative is fine; the terminal-position adverb adds stress).

Comment: Both are perfectly correct. One property of English as opposed to many another language is that on the level you suggest, that kind of difference never matters.