# Correct words order in the sentence

Tags: word-order

What would be the correct sentence:

- Designed to specifically work with
- Designed specifically to work with
- Designed to work specifically with

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position of the adverb "substantially".](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307591/position-of-the-adverb-substantially) Also [Position of adverb “implicitly”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62718/position-of-adverb-implicitly) and doubtless others.

Comment: Apart from where to place its adverb, the word *designed* always sounds counterproductive in advertising. Picture the Legal department saying "For-God-sake, don't promise 'em our product *does* anything, only that it was designed to do that stuff!"